# usage of ref in vue3

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I wrote a vue3 component which uses the VirtualScroller from PrimeVue and I would like to scroll to the end of the scroller each time I'm adding new elements. For that, there is scrollInView method which is defined on the component and documented [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/virtualscroller)

My code looks like this (it's typescript with vue-class-component and single file syntax):

```
<template>
 ...
   <VirtualScroller :items="content" :itemSize="50" class="streamscroller" ref="streamscroller">
      <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
        <pre>{{ item }}</pre>
      </template>
    </VirtualScroller>
...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
...
import { ref, ComponentPublicInstance } from "vue";
import VirtualScroller from "primevue/virtualscroller";
...
@Options({
  components: {
    VirtualScroller,
...
  },
})
export default class StreamResultViewer extends Vue {
  streamscroller = ref<ComponentPublicInstance<VirtualScroller>>();
  content: string [] = [ "No output" ];
...
  mounted(): void {
...
    console.debug("scroller mounted: ", this.streamscroller.value);   // <=== here, already the value is indefined
  }
  onData(msg: string): void {
      const lines = msg.split('\n');
      const content =  [...this.content, ...lines];
      this.content = content;
      console.debug("scroller: ", this.streamscroller.value);   // <== always undefined
      this.streamscroller.value?.scrollInView(this.content.length, 'to-end', 'smooth');   // <== so never called
  }
...
```

The virtual scroller works well (I can add lines each time they arrives and the scroll bar  moves...) but I can never call the scroll method because the ref is undefined...

I'd be very grateful for any clue...

Thank you

Comment: did you try just:  streamscroller = ref(null)

Comment: @jeremycastelli, yes, I tried, it does not work better (and I have to "fake" the typescript typing to do that)

Comment: ok, 2 thoughts (3 actually) : 1 - In my code I do something looking more like this `const streamscroller: Ref<myType> = ref(null);`
2- I'm wondering if ref() is only usable with composition API.
3- I was using vue-class-component just like you and I think for the same reasons. I totally dropped it since the composition API and the new script setup that appeared with v3.2 https://learnvue.co/2021/05/explaining-the-new-script-setup-type-in-vue-3-major-takeaways-from-the-rfc/#a-rundown-of-script-setup`. Much cleaner, no bolerplate, better typing, and one less library

Comment: Thanks you Jeremy. Actually Evan You himself told me in an issue that vue-class-component was not recommended anymore so I'll look at your link. Meanwhile, I found a workaround as described in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I found is too use $refs like this:

```
onData(msg: string): void {
  const lines = msg.split('\n');
  const content = [...this.content, ...lines];
  this.content = content;
  const scroller = this.$refs.streamscroller as VirtualScroller;
  scroller.scrollInView(this.content.length, 'to-end', 'smooth');
}
```

This way, I am able to call the scrolling method and it works fine.

If someone can explain how it should work normally with ref<T>() in the vue-class-component + typescript mode, I'd be glad to hear that.